# Bioshock Infinite not loading autosaves

Tags: xbox-360, bioshock-infinite

So for some reason, be it game or console related, my game has me stuck with my checkpoint set at the First Lady Aerodome. No matter how far I advance, if I try to quit or press "restart last checkpoint" in the menu, it'll keep sending me back to to where I was hours ago.

This last time I noticed that if I tried to return to the Main Menu, a warning popped up telling me my last save was in November of 2005. Clearly this is not correct. Has anyone else encountered this and know how to fix it?

Comment: What storage device are you using?

Comment: I have this same problem! I've played the same several chapters over and over again :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to the load chapter option instead of selecting continue and load the most recent chapter.

Note: The time and date on the auto-saves may be wrong. they were for me.

Here is a link with a list of chapters
http://fortfrolic.com/bioshock-infinite/chapter-list/

Answer (score 2):

Brandon Simnacher has the correct answer on how to get around this, but I wanted to post why this is happening. I see this as one of two potential issues.

### Started Playing Online, Continued Playing Offline

The issue is a by-product of saving games while connected on- or offline. When your system is offline and you save a game, it reverts to the release date for the hardware, in this case November 21, 2005. So what might have happened was you started playing Bioshock Infinite online, giving autosaves a date in April of 2013, and then continued playing offline, giving your autosaves a date of November 21, 2005. The Continue option looks for the most recent date, which in your case would have been the last time you were online. This would also be earlier in the storyline for you.

For example:

1. You play chapters 1-8 while your Xbox is connected to the internet. All saves dates are in April 2013.
2. You continue the next day while not connected to the internet, making it through chapter 12. Chapters 9-12 have save dates of November 21, 2005.
3. You go to "Continue" your game the following day, but Bioshock sees that your most recent save date was in April 2013, taking you back to the beginning of Chapter 9.

The best solution so that this doesn't happen is to make sure that you are always online when playing the game (giving all of your saves sequential date information). If this isn't an option, navigate to the Load option instead of using Continue.

### Always Playing Offline

This may be a problem of never being online as well. If you are never online, every time you turn on your system it will think it is the same day of 2005 (sometime in November IIRC). So if you play one day starting at noon and go for four hours, you'll get save times ending at 4pm on November 21, 2005. When you come back the following day, you start playing at noon and play for 2 hours, you'll get save times ending at 2pm on November 21, 2005. How your saves would look to Bioshock Infinite:

1. Day 1: Play for four hours, last save is at 4pm on November 21, 2005.
2. Day 2: Hit continue, game loads save from 4pm on November 21, 2005. Play for 2 hours, last save is at 2pm on November 21, 2005.
3. Day 3: Hit continue, game loads save from 4pm on November 21, 2005 since that is the most recent save date.

Comment: This explains things since my Xbox couldn't get internet connection in my dorm. Thanks for the useful information =)